# Graphing number of rows over time in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, graph

I have a data frame with rows of datetime elements (or perhaps they're text, I'm reading them in from a csv)Ex:.

`2017-07-14 09:10:40
2017-07-14 09:10:24
2017-07-14 09:10:22
2017-07-14 09:09:49
2017-07-14 09:09:48
2017-07-14 09:09:48
2017-07-14 09:09:26
2017-07-14 09:09:04
2017-07-14 09:08:35
2017-07-14 09:08:17
2017-07-14 09:08:07`

I'd like to graph how many rows there are per date, or per hour.
(dates on x axis and number of rows on y axis).

How can I do that? I recognize that I'll need to do a count, but I don't know what to do with the number once I have it for each date. I guess I'll need to map it to a new df or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want bar plot?

Comment: bar plot works! Line plot is fine too. Just trying to see the trends/change in rate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) or [`dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), last [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.date).size().plot()
```

Or:

```
#change axis name to Hours by rename
df = df.groupby(df['Date'].rename('Hours').dt.hour).size().plot()
```

Sample:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=15, freq='3.5H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng})  
print (df)
                  Date
0  2017-04-03 00:00:00
1  2017-04-03 03:30:00
2  2017-04-03 07:00:00
3  2017-04-03 10:30:00
4  2017-04-03 14:00:00
5  2017-04-03 17:30:00
6  2017-04-03 21:00:00
7  2017-04-04 00:30:00
8  2017-04-04 04:00:00
9  2017-04-04 07:30:00
10 2017-04-04 11:00:00
11 2017-04-04 14:30:00
12 2017-04-04 18:00:00
13 2017-04-04 21:30:00
14 2017-04-05 01:00:00

print (df.groupby(df['Date'].rename('Hours').dt.hour).size())
Hours
0     2
1     1
3     1
4     1
7     2
10    1
11    1
14    2
17    1
18    1
21    2
dtype: int64
```

---

```
df.groupby(df['Date'].rename('Hours').dt.hour).size().plot()
```

[image: graph]

```
df.groupby(df['Date'].rename('Hours').dt.hour).size().plot.bar()
```

[image: graph1]

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values` but all my values in the date column are formatted like `2017-07-14 09:07:29` am I missing something?

Comment: Need cast to dates, `df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])`

Comment: I'm getting `cannot convert an object of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to a datetimelike index`

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: sample data added. I realized that since I'm reading in from a csv maybe I need to interpret the dates as strings, not date times.

Comment: Thanks, how do you read it from `csv`? I think you need `parse_dates` parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) -  `pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=[0])` - `[0]` is first column, change it if necessary.